# Construction of "etale associated-sheaf" in Rotman's

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

On [pg 282 Prop 5.68](http://www.math.unam.mx/javier/homologica/rotman.pdf) Rotman makes the following construction given a presheaf $P$ of abelian groups over a space $X$. The construction is as follows: For $P^{et}:= (E^{et}, p^{et},X)$.

[image]

I am struggling in understanding the topolgoy defined on $E^{et}$.

There are two statements, on -2 line of pg 282,

> How is lemma 5.30 (ii) applied?  Why is $\langle \tau, W \rangle \subseteq \langle \sigma, U \rangle \cap \langle \sigma' , U' \rangle $?

Lastly

> Why is this the coarsest topology on $E$ making all sections continuous. What are the sections?